# Need a simple alternative Api Authentication system in an already built Api using Asp.Net MVC4 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, http-headers, httpwebrequest, api-auth

I have completed working on an Api using C# in a Asp.Net MVC4 application project. Now there is a need to add an authentication process in the completed Api. I need guidance to make the authentication using username and password and then use httpheader, httpwebrequest or httpclient for adding header authorization system. I am not that experienced in this, so I am thinking of any easy/simplest way to add the authentication system to the Api via username and password.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi akistack, and welcome to Stack Overflow. What options have you looked at so far?

Comment: Got a suggestion which seemed easy but I am a bit confused though about its implementation. The suggestion was to enter username and password in authorization basic type and then encode and decode sth then verify and allow the api call or else show error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that questions get reviewed, and this question is too broad. It's much better to ask a specific question based on your attempt (code) and including all details for others to help effectively. I suggest to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).